# How to detect the owner of an async call response

Tags: .net, rest, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I 'm calling a web service method in a timer delegate every 5 seconds using async/await. The response is a number in json format. The problem is that the server of the web service is pretty slow and inconsistent. The response is coming sometimes immediately under 1 seconds, but it isn't a rare case that i wait for a response 5-10 seconds. My question is how i can detect which response is belonging to which call.

For example:

```
Call1 at 20:00:00
Call2 at 20:00:05

ResponseA at 20:00:07
ResponseB at 20:00:09
```

How should i deduct now if ResponseA is belonging to call1 or call2 ?

What I want to do is to omit/ignore ResponseB for further data processing, if it belongs to Call1, since it is an outdated data in my case.

Alternatively, i could make the next(second) webcall than when i get the response from the previous(first) webcall, but this would be inefficient since a webcall can lag up to 15 seconds in worst case.

Comment: Do you control the server?

Comment: where are you calling it from? e.g. ajax, windows application, etc

Comment: @Palle: No I don't control the server.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I am calling it from a WPF application.